# Basic Nim game in Haskell

Tags: game, haskell

I am starting to learn Haskell, and following [Dr. Erik Meijer lectures online](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals), he suggests as an exercise to implement the game of [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) in Haskell, so I implemented a really basic game for two players (no computer player).

I can imagine that this code is far from being good Haskell, and I accept all possible criticism and suggestions about it (if you can link me to other lectures/talks/guidelines, I appreciate it), but there are some aspects that I would love to ask you:

1. **The comments**: I am not really sure how am I supposed to document the code in Haskell, so I just tried to explain each of the methods before its declaration. If there is another convention, please let me know.
2. **The parenthesis**: Should I use more the `$` or `.` operators than parenthesis? I kind of struggle with trying to use composition with functions when there is more than one argument.
3. **The nested `do` blocks**: I fixed an error doing it, but it feels incredibly hacky and I don't really understand why the compiler is not able to understand the code when there is more than one line inside an if clause (doesn't matter which one, both were problematic). If I don't put the `do` keyword, the compiler was interpreting that `putStrLine` was receiving 4 arguments: its real argument and the next function call (`turn board player`, for instance). Why did it happen?

This is the code itself:

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
import qualified Data.Foldable as Fol
import qualified Data.List as List
import Data.Maybe

-- Player type is used to take control of the turns and who wins
data Player = One | Two deriving (Show, Eq)

-- Change player returns the player that is NOT the one passed as argument
change :: Player -> Player
change One = Two
change Two = One

-- Board is an alias for a Sequence of Ints, as they allow us to update single
-- elements in easily.
type Board = Seq.Seq Int

-- This is the initial board structure
initialBoard :: Board
initialBoard = Seq.fromList [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

-- The move method checks if the a movement can be executed and returns the
-- updated board in case it is possible
move :: Board -> (Int, Int) -> Maybe Board
move board (row, stars)
  | and [(Seq.index board row) >= stars,
          row < 5] = Just (Seq.adjust (\x -> x - stars) row board)
  | otherwise = Nothing

-- The display methods transforms a Board into a nice, enumerated String of
-- asterisks
display :: Board -> String
display board = List.intercalate "\n" (zipWith (++) numbers (stars board))
                where numbers = ["1. ", "2. ", "3. ", "4. ", "5. "]
                      stars board = [(concat . take n) (repeat "* ")
                                    | n <- Fol.toList board]

-- The next methods are the ones that control IO
main :: IO ()
main = nim

-- Main method welcomes the player, displays the initial board and calls the
-- first turn
nim :: IO ()
nim = do putStrLn "Welcome to nim!"
         putStrLn (display initialBoard)
         turn initialBoard One

-- The turn method displays the player and asks for a movement, then checks if
-- there was a problem performing that movement and continues the game. This is
-- the main game loop
turn :: Board -> Player -> IO ()
turn board player = do putStrLn ("\nIt's your turn, Player " ++ (show player) ++ "!")
                       putStrLn "Choose a row to remove stars!"
                       row <- getLine
                       putStrLn "How many stars do you want to remove?"
                       stars <- getLine
                       let newBoard = move board ((read row) - 1, read stars)
                       if newBoard == Nothing
                         then do putStrLn "Not valid movement"
                                 turn board player
                         else isOver (fromJust newBoard) (change player)

-- isOver checks if the Board is empty, and checks whether the game is over or
-- the next turn must be called
isOver :: Board -> Player -> IO()
isOver board player = do if board == Seq.fromList [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                           then putStrLn ("Congratulations, Player " ++ (show player)
                                         ++ ", you win!")
                           else do putStrLn ""
                                   putStrLn (display board)
                                   turn board player
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Haskell generates rich documentation from specially marked up comments using [Haddock](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/index.html). If you're finding it difficult to write a description that does more than restate the type give some [usage examples](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html#idm140354810775744). E.g.,

   ```
   >>> change One
   Two
   ```

   Then consider future proofing your examples with [doctest](https://github.com/sol/doctest#readme).
2. This is fine, don't worry about it.
3. (This explanation trades rigor for accessibility. Hopefully.)

   The contents of the `then` and `else` blocks aren't part of the overall `turn` `do`-block. The `if` statement returns whichever of `then` or `else` based on the given predicate, which in your case *must* be an `IO` monad action, but in the general case of `if`s doesn't *have* to be.

   While `if`/`then`/`else` is syntax, consider this function definition which is equivalent and *not* syntax.

   ```
   boolCase :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
   boolCase True  a _ = a
   boolCase False _ b = b
   ```

   So your broken `if` statement was the same as—

   ```
   boolCase (newBoard == Nothing)
            (putStrLn "Not valid movement"
             turn board player)
            (isOver (fromJust newBoard) (changePlayer))
   ```

   Now that it looks like a normal function call do you see the problem with the second argument to `boolCase`? Without explicitly using `do` you *are* calling `putStrLn` with four arguments as that line break is no longer meaningful. This is the same as when you use `if`/`then`/`else`. Just because you are using an `if` in a `do`-block doesn't mean that the contents of `then` and `else` are in that same `do`-block.

---

Use type aliases to disambiguate repeated types that would be inconvenient to `newtype`. This improves your documentation without needing to write boring comments too!

```
type Row = Int
type Stars = Int
```

Don't tuple your arguments to functions unnecessarily. E.g., use `move :: Board -> Row -> Stars -> Maybe Board` instead of what you have now.

`move` has an error in that it checks the number of stars in a row before it checks that the row is in bounds.

`move` is kinda hairy with that multi-line guard. Here's an alternate version (one of many possible!) that takes advantage of the `Alternative` instance of `Maybe` (and should take advantage of the new `ApplicativeDo` extension if you enable it!).

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

move :: Board -> Row -> Stars -> Maybe Board
move board row stars = do
    guard $ 0 <= row && row < 5
    guard $ stars <= board `Seq.index` row
    pure $ Seq.adjust (subtract stars) row board
```

Here's an alternate version of `display` too. Take advantage of pre-existing functions with semantically meaningful names!

```
import Data.List (intersperse, replicate)

display :: Board -> String
display board = unlines $ zipWith (++) numbers (stars board)
  where
    numbers = ["1. ", "2. ", "3. ", "4. ", "5. "]
    stars = map (intersperse ' ' . flip replicate '*') . toList
```

Your game play and display logic is smeared across `nim`, `turn` and `isOver`. Try extracting the pure components into reusable, nameable functions (like the proposition in `isOver`). Instead of `if` and then `fromJust`, use a `case` statement (`case newBoard of Nothing -> ...; Just b -> ...`). Use a safe version of `read` (`Text.Read.readMaybe`) and deal with errors properly.

You might also want to use `Data.Array` instead of `Data.Sequence` for constant time indexing.

With practice and familiarity I think you'll do fine! This is really very good for a beginner.

Comment: In addition to what Rowan said I would also try to eliminate the explicit recursion: Instead of calling turn/isOver recursively from each other, return the new arguments back to the caller, which will then handle passing the data on. That way, you can understand all data flow just by reading the caller. You can then use the library Control.Monad.Loops to try and find a common pattern that you can apply in the caller in place of recursion.

Comment: Thank you both! I am learning functional programming on my own, so this feedback is incredibly useful.